# Boot-repair error after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 from 7. I have a dual boot setup with Ubuntu. Upon reboot, I entered Grub rescue mode
"Error: unknown filesystem"
I was able to get to the Grub menu and boot using "set boot" and "set prefix", but I am not able to permanently repair Grub; I enter rescue mode each time I reboot.

I tried Ubuntu live CD and ran boot-repair, but it does not complete. It gives the error:

"LegacyWindows detected. The boot of your PC is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode.
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?"

I am not sure how to change to BIOS compatibility mode.

I checked BIOS mode on Windows 10 and it says "Legacy".

I have not updated the BIOS in a while, updates are available. I just don't want to disturb the system any further at this point.

This is the report from Boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ChHmDHz5W7/

Thanks!
Barry

Comment: What versions of Ubuntu? It says on line 108 17.04 and 12.04, both are EoL or end of life. You need current installs. And only put a Windows boot loader in sda. Since UEFI hardware better to reinstall both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. How you boot USB install media for both Windows & Ubuntu from UEFI menu is how it installs. Errors on Windows may require Windows fixes or reinstall anyway. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen 20.10 uses grub for both
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred It also looks like OP is running Windows 7 which is also EOL as of January 2020.

Comment: I was able to repair the MBR using boot-repair and now Windows 10 boots directly without the Grub menu. I made a recovery drive for Windows. Windows boot shows legacy mode, not EFI. Grub was using EFI. I think that mismatch was causing the problem.